# Maybe all is not as it seams

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

1. What location is depicted in the below, edited image? (First answered by @Rand al'Thor)
2. What type of game, simulation or software was used to create the original, unedited image (not shown here)? Please explain your reasoning.
3. Bonus points: Can you find the original, unedited image? You may have to do some browsing but it's publicly available and not on an obscure site.

(Note: generative AI was not used to create or edit this image)

I'll accept an answer for just q1+q2, but I'll prioritise an answer if it addresses q3 as well.

Hints:

> Three literary sisters (6 letters, begins with B)

> The title is not a typo, but "all is not as it seam" would be more helpful

> Question 2 is intentionally misleading when it refers to software/game/simulation. To be clear, there is an original unedited image, and I modified it to produce the one shown here. Note that even the edited one displays a visible seam in one corner of the image. This is also visible in the original. Why is there a seam at all?

> New hint: There is a seam in the top-right of the image, where there is an inconsistency not only in the wall of the harbour but also one of the walking characters is only half-shown. This is not an intentional seam. It is an indicator of what software was used to create the original image.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Channelling my inner [Rainbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trevor_Rainbolt) ...

You are in

> Bronte Harbour, Oakville, Ontario, Canada.

This is confirmed by looking at the images from

> Google Maps (note the position of the benches and the angle between the paths):
>
>  [image: satellite view]
>
>  Google Street View (note the shape of the lamp-posts and the positions of the trees):
>   [image: from street view]

Comparing with your image:

> [image: with boxes around the matching features]

So this is clearly the place, but I don't know what software you used to create this image, which is taken from an angle not consistent with either a satellite picture or Google Street View images.

Comment: This is absolutely the place! This is what the hint "Three literary sisters (6 letters, begins with B)" was trying to indicate.

Because I'm not sure how fair the rest of the question is, I'll add a hint to the original question.

Comment: Could the picture by OP be created in 'Second Life' or some similar virtual reality game/ environment? I haven't played it so I don't know whether one could use it to make a representation that close to the original.

Comment: @quarague See, this is my problem - I'm not familiar with *any* video games or virtual reality stuff, so I have no idea how to answer that part. I only know Geoguessr, which uses Google Street View data so it doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: There is a seam in the top-right of the image, where there is an inconsistency not only in the wall of the harbour but also one of the walking characters is only half-shown. This is not an intentional seam. It is an indicator of what kind of software was used to create the original image.

Comment: You can get a much better match to the supplied image with ROT13(Ovat'f Oveq'f-rlr ivrj. ). But there are still some mismatches.